# how to size and align flot graphs

Tags: jquery, flot

By default flot sizes the graph and axis labels to fix inside the div container. If you have a series of graphs on a page, with different variables in each graph, the sizes of the axis labels is different and the graph canvases are therefore different sizes and don't align neatly.

Is there a way to set the size and position of the flot canvas so that the graphs are a fixed size and position within the containers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not exactly, no.  What you can do is specify how wide/high the axis labels should be, which will force the canvases to line up between different graphs.

From the [API.txt](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/API.txt):

> "labelWidth" and "labelHeight" specifies a fixed size of the tick
>   labels in pixels. They're useful in case you need to align several
>   plots. "reserveSpace" means that even if an axis isn't shown, Flot
>   should reserve space for it - it is useful in combination with
>   labelWidth and labelHeight for aligning multi-axis charts.

Beyond that, if you wanted the actual axes to be the same between graphs, you would need to establish what the global min/max is for each axis between all your data sets, and then specify that for each axis in each graph.

Comment: the problem I was having was all the graphs have different variables and some have multiple y-axes. But managed to coax them all to line up by setting the widths and adding invisible fake y scales so the graphs all had the same number.